# **Mejorar la lógica de programación**

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esta comunidad y me llamo **Lizan**, este año he comenzado un  ciclo superior de DAM, y tengo atravesado programación y el problema es que a la hora de hacer los ejercicios no se como llevarlos acabo.
no tengo ni idea de que usar en cada momento y porque he de usarlo.

¿alguien podría darme algún consejo para mejorar o aprender la lógica?

muchísimas *gracias* de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Cuando tengas un problema concreto, con gusto te vamos a ayudar, pero una pregunta asi, no tiene respuesta en este sitio. Tambien, puedes pasar por el [chat] cuando tengas suficiente reputacion...

Comment: Creo que no hay un manual. Sí hay patrones de diseño que te pueden facilitar el desarrollo. No te frustres si no sabes enseguida cómo resolver un problema. Puedo sugerir que cuánto más practiques mejor y te ayudes de chatGPT o copilot (el último comete menos errores programando).

Comment: Cuando tengas un error que no sepas cómo resolver, eres más que bienvenido a ver si alguien ya lo tuvo y sino preguntar en el sitio. No olvides mostrar lo que intentaste o lo que fuese necesario para poder reproducir el error.